# The method renderJSON(Map<String,String>) is undefined

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, response, render

I have `Play framework 2.0.4` installed. For the java app I have, I want to render response in `JSON` format.

But when I was using `renderJSON`, compiler gives:

> The method `renderJSON(Map<String,String>)` is undefined for the type Status

what am I missing here?

```
public class Status extends Controller {

    public static void myMethod(String url) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("id", "1069");
        map.put("url", url);
        renderJSON(map);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are trying to port an application from version 1 to 2? In Play 2, this is how you return a JSON response:

```
ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
result.put("id", "1069");
result.put("url", url);
return ok(result);
```

You should also have a look at the [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaJsonRequests).